# Repeat loop if input is 'y'

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class DrawTriangle
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Do you want to see a triangle? Insert y to continue");
    String input = scan.next();
    boolean cont = false;

    if ((input.equals("y")))
    {
        cont = true;
        double a = (40);
        double b = (30);
        double height = (Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
        for (int x = 1; x <= height; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height - x; y++) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) 
            {
                System.out.print("x ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
    else 
    {
        cont = false;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("Program ended");
    }

}
}
```

I need the program to draw a triangle when a user enters 'y'. This works, however I need the program to then ask the user to again enter an input if the user previously pressed 'y'. Also I'm not sure if my random numbers are working, as everytime the triangle is the same size...

Comment: Clearly, the question and reading user input must be inside a loop if you want to repeat it. You can use `while (true)` and `break` when you detect `!input.equals("y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the if statement to while, ask user input again in the loop, and remove the else

```
while ((input.equals("y")))
{
    cont = true;
    double a = (40);
    double b = (30);
    double height = (Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
    for (int x = 1; x <= height; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height - x; y++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) 
        {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println ("Do you want to see a triangle? Insert y to continue");
    input = scan.next();

}

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Program ended");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to swap your if statement for a loop as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class DrawTriangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cont = false;
        String input = "y";
        while (input.equals("y"))
            {
                System.out.println ("Do you want to see a triangle? Insert y to continue");
                input = scan.next();
                cont = true;
                double a = (40);
                double b = (30);
                double height = (Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
                for (int x = 1; x <= height; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < height - x; y++) 
                            {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) 
                            {
                                System.out.print("x ");
                            }
                        System.out.println();

                    }

            }
                        cont = false;
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println ("Program ended");

    }
}
```